# How to measure the amount of time taken in classes/functions using multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, time, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing module in my code, and I want to count the time taken for each class. There are 5 classes, e.g. `class A, class B, ... , class E`, which are assembled by `class X`. `class Y` invokes several datasets that needed to be processed by `class X` (an instance of `class X`).

I have set a timer (`time.time()`) in `class X` to see how much time each dataset will take, and timers in `class A-E` to test out how much time each step will take.

The multiprocessing is used in `class Y`, the pool is set to 4, and map the main function of `class X` to the datasets.

The problem is the total time of processing all the datasets is even less than an individual step (summing up for processing the data). How to fix this?

Comment: Basically, it's not adding up, right? Just want to make sure I understand the  question.

Comment: @XamuelSchulman you are correct, it doesn't added up.

Comment: Can you attach the relevant code? I need to see it to fully understand what is going on.